# Is it possible to use a div as a background image of another div?

Tags: css, html

I want this so I can give a set of rotating tiles the background image of the div that's behind the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done when you set a parent div that gives the `background-image` property to it.

And put a div inside of the parent one .

An example.

**CSS :**

```
.parent {
    background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif');
}

.child {
    background : rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    height : 50px;
    width : 100px;
    opacity : 0.7;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="child">
        Two
    </div>

</div>
```

---

### **Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9N2L/)**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want a div placed exactly over another div. If so you can use position relative and then get the width and height of the parent div and place second div exactly over it.